# Why does subprocess.Popen want a list instead of a string?

Tags: python

I'd like to understand what is going on under the hood in terms of why Popen wants a list instead of a string.  Example:

```
cmd_desired = 'func -a arg1 arg2'
subprocess.Popen(cmd_desired)  # Doesn't work
list_cmd = cmd_desired.split()
subprocess.Popen(list_cmd)  # Works
subprocess.Popen(cmd_desired, shell=True)  # Also works
```

What's going on?

Comment: `cmd_desired.split()` is not a dict.

Comment: Sorry, list.  I'll fix.  Nice of someone to -1 me.

Answer (score 3):

The question is erring in that it refers to the contents of `dict_cmd` as a dictionary.  It is a list, for example `['func', '-a', 'arg1', 'arg2']`.  As such, `dict_cmd` is not a good name for the variable.  Renaming it accordingly, we have:

```
cmd_desired = 'func -a arg1 arg2'
list_cmd = cmd_desired.split()
```

And then the options are:

```
subprocess.Popen(list_cmd)  # Works
```

or:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd_desired, shell=True)  # Also works
```

Of these options, using a list rather than a string is usually preferable, because it maps more or less directly onto the how the underlying system call (called `execve`) works, which is used to actually execute the command in the forked subprocess.  Here is the prototype for `execve` in C:

```
int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

The second argument `argv` is an array of `char *`, which corresponds closely to a list of strings in Python.

Where a space-separated string is used instead of a list, this cannot be passed directly to `execve`.  It can be used in combination with `shell=True` as the question indicates, and then a shell is invoked as an intermediate process.  The shell will then interpret spaces as argument separators, and use it to split the string into an array of arguments that can be passed to `execve`. The shell will also interpret various other characters in the command string (for example `>` for output redirection).

Whether the use of a shell is desirable will depend on the application, but for example if there are arguments containing spaces, they will need to be protected from being split into different arguments if using a shell.  This is not a concern when using the list version.

Answer (score 1):

Per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) *args* can be a **sequence** or a string (emphasis mine):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). **If passing a single string, either shell must be True** ... or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

What's likely going on "under the hood" is that the shell parses the arguments for you when `shell=True`; otherwise, you have to provide the sequence or arguments yourself.